# Get specific bytes in payload from a pcap file

Tags: python, parsing, scapy, pcap

I have a PCAP file which I am parsing using Scapy,

I have managed to dump the payload to a hexdump by using the code bellow

```
pkts = rdpcap('Sink.pcap')
print hexdump(pkts[0][2].load)
```

I get the output

```
0000   00 00 00 *01* 58 2F AC 47  01 D8 1E 5F 00 00 00 01   ....X/.G..._....
0010   00 0A 5E 32 08 00 08 00  08 00 08 00 08 00 08 00   ..^2............
0020   08 00 08 00 08 00 08 00  08 00 08 00 08 00 08 00   ................
0030   08 00 08 00 08 00 08 00  08 00 08 00               ............
None
```

What I want to do is for example print only the 4th byte (0x01) that is. (Surrounded by stars), how would I do this? Do I convert the hexdump to a string and then do string parsing or can I use the Scapy library to achieve this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean

```
print pkts[0][2].load[3]
```

or maybe as hex and char

```
val = pkts[0][2].load[3]
print "%x %s" % (ord(val), val)
```

Of course you can use it with `hexdump` too

```
print hexdump( pkts[0][2].load[3] )
```